Restore and update soft deleted record Go Gorm
We are creating a translation app with a golang and gorm backend
This is our POSTGRES database table:
DataBase Table screenshot
This is our Go Struct:
type TermLocale struct {
    models.Model
    JsonLdId    models.ResourceId `gorm:"-" jsonld:"@id" json:"-" swaggertype:"primitive,string"`
    JsonLdType  types.JsonString  `gorm:"-" jsonld:"@type" json:"-" swaggertype:"primitive,string"`
    TermID      uint              `api:"default" gorm:"type:int;uniqueIndex:idx_term_locales" jsonld:"-" json:"-"`
    Term        *Term             `api:"default,resourceId" gorm:"foreignKey:TermID;references:ID" jsonld:"term" json:"term" swaggertype:"primitive,string"`
    LocaleID    uint              `api:"default" gorm:"type:int;uniqueIndex:idx_term_locales" jsonld:"-" json:"-"`
    Locale      *Locale           `api:"default,resourceId" gorm:"foreignKey:LocaleID;references:ID" jsonld:"locale" json:"locale" swaggertype:"primitive,string"`
    Translation string            `api:"default" gorm:"type:text" jsonld:"translation" json:"translation" swaggertype:"primitive,string"`
}

As you can see we have some deleted records (with deleted_at data), but we want to have the possibility to restore and update record, for exemple if the user set again a translation for the term_id and locale_id (we mark records as deleted when the user set a translation to empty string)
Today we have this error:
`ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_term_locales" (SQLSTATE 23505)
[34.272ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "term_locales" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","term_id","locale_id","translation") VALUES ('2024-06-06 17:33:25.389','2024-06-06 17:33:25.389',NULL,1366,2,'test') RETURNING "id"`
We have try to use Unscoped to get the record and remove the deleted_at with gorm.DeletedAt{} before .Updates() update record but it's not really working (How can I restore data that I soft deleted with gorm deletedAt)
Here is the code:
func (c *TermLocaleController) PostItem(context *gin.Context) {
    termLocal := systemModel.TermLocale{}
    var err error

    ctxDefinition := controllers.ContextDefinition{JsonFields: []string{"*"}}
    requestContext := controllers.NewRequestContext(context, ctxDefinition, reflect.TypeOf(systemModel.TermLocale{}))

    termId := context.Param("id")
    if termId == "" {
        c.common.SendError(requestContext, 400, errors_custom.NewBadRequestError(errors.New("term missing")))
        return
    }
    localeId := context.Param("locale")
    if localeId == "" {
        c.common.SendError(requestContext, 400, errors_custom.NewBadRequestError(errors.New("locale missing")))
        return
    }

    // get and check JSON
    err = helpers.BindJSON(context, &termLocal)
    if err != nil {
        c.common.SendError(requestContext, 400, errors_custom.NewBadRequestError(err))
        return
    }

    dataAccess := dba.NewDatabaseAccess()
    // Get termLocales
    requestTermLocaleContext := controllers.NewRequestContext(context, ctxDefinition, reflect.TypeOf(systemModel.TermLocale{}))
    termLocalRepository := systemRepository.NewTermLocaleRepository(dataAccess, dataAccess.NewQueryContext(requestTermLocaleContext))
    termLocaleOfTermLocal, errTermLocale := termLocalRepository.FindOneByTermAndLocale(termId, localeId)

    // Get locales
    requestLocaleContext := controllers.NewRequestContext(context, ctxDefinition, reflect.TypeOf(systemModel.Locale{}))
    localeRepository := systemRepository.NewLocaleRepository(dataAccess, dataAccess.NewQueryContext(requestLocaleContext).AddField("Id"))
    localeOfTermLocal, errLocale := localeRepository.FindOneByIdOrCode(localeId)
    if errLocale != nil {
        c.common.SendError(requestLocaleContext, 400, errors_custom.NewBadRequestError(errLocale))
        return
    }

    // Get terms
    requestTermContext := controllers.NewRequestContext(context, ctxDefinition, reflect.TypeOf(systemModel.Term{}))
    termRepository := systemRepository.NewTermRepository(dataAccess, dataAccess.NewQueryContext(requestTermContext))
    termOfTermLocale, errTerm := termRepository.FindOneByIdOrKey(termId)
    if errTerm != nil {
        c.common.SendError(requestTermContext, 400, errors_custom.NewBadRequestError(errTerm))
        return
    }

    termLocal.Locale = localeOfTermLocal
    termLocal.Term = termOfTermLocale

    tx := dataAccess.DB()
    if errTermLocale == nil {
        tx = tx.Model(termLocaleOfTermLocal).Updates(&termLocal)
    } else {
        tx = tx.Create(&termLocal)
    }

    if tx.Error == nil {
        for _, aDomain := range termOfTermLocale.Domains {
            stringCmd := application.GetAppData().ClientRedis.Keys(context2.TODO(), "controllers_system_domain_getdomainsubresourcetermlocalesscollection_result_"+aDomain.Name+"_"+localeOfTermLocal.Code)
            if len(stringCmd.Val()) > 0 {
                application.GetAppData().ClientRedis.Del(context2.TODO(), stringCmd.Val()...)
            }

        }
        tx.Commit()
        c.common.SendSuccessItem(requestContext, 201, termLocal)
    } else {
        tx.Rollback()
        c.common.SendError(requestContext, 500, errors_custom.NewServerError(tx.Error))
    }

    return
}


You forgot to show your code.

@zerkms, sorry, I've updated with the code, let me know if you need more
